# How can I make htaccess ignore or 404 urls like this page/27/?p=yvwasetgrnv

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

After I redesigned my site to offer way more helpful content and tutorials, Google killed my rankings. I think I discovered one of the reasons...

Somehow urls like this are being indexed. I should only have maybe 1-2k indexed pages but i have 5,000, many of them like this:

site.com**/page/27/?p=yvwasetgrnv**

I checked what Wordpress SEO plugin is telling google is the canonical url, and the news isn't good: 
site.com/business/why-is-your-prospective-customer-not-buying**/page/27/**...

That isn't even a real page on my site. The title you see in there is for a blog post, but due to the parameters in the url, wordpress is listing a directory page, and many more pages of the same thing.

I need to remove these duplicates from the index and 404 them all on my site.

How can I use .htaccess to accomplish that?

Comment: do you have a list of query string parameters that are invalid, or some other way to identify which ULRs are valid/invalid e.g. example URLs or other rules?

Comment: I would try to fix the root problem, namely the incorrect canonical link elements in your html.

Comment: Ulrich: I would like all ?p= to redirect to the actual page permalink (canonical url). I'm a bit stumped about the /page/27/ problem, since telling the server anything with /page/ is wrong, is not the way to go as i will lose my pagination.

Gerben: I wish I could but the canonicals are automatically generated by Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also agree that getting to the root cause is the ideal approach.

However, if you cannot do that you can try adding the following to your .htaccess file, preferably at the top (if there are other rules there).

It will remove strip out all query string params if the `p` query string param is present. I am assuming that the canonical url is the URL without the Query string params

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if a request has a p query string parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p= [NC]
#then 301 redirect to URL without any query string parameters
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Actually it appears that the query string isn't the real problem. 

The canonical url generated by Wordpress SEO does not include the query string, so that's great. BUT the canonical url includes the /page/29/ or whatever page... That pagination shouldn't exist in this case.

You can see here: http://www.webhostingbreak.com/page/20/?p=abufgcxtxxijn

the p= is calling an actual post, but because of the pagination in the url, it's trying to show an archive. So, we have 1 post with infinite pagination.

I shouldn't have ANY urls on my site with pagination from the root i.e. site.com/page/1/

Comment: So, it seems the solution (sorry I didn't see this before) is to use htaccess to remove the /page/1/ (pagination) from a url if it's coming right after the .com/ but not anywhere else